# Why is ngrok not loading php in my views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frontend, ngrok, tunneling

I have an codeigniter application that I'm trying to expose using ngrok. All the assets, stylesheets, etc seem to be loading correctly. However, the php I've written in my views is commented out when I check chrome developer tools. This causes unexpected behaviour, and things to be displayed when they shouldn't be. [ngrok vs localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObKcb.jpg) The image shows one example when I use php in my views to hide or display content, I've included also a screenshot of chrome developer tools. [chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZLBE.png). As you can see php manipulating my html is comented out. I'm serving the app using `php -S localhost:port` and `ngrok http port`. I haven't been able to find an explaination, for why this error might be occuring, usually ngrok has problms with loading assets. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: PHP on the frontend? PHP is a _server_-side language. "_Inline PHP_"? PHP should be parsed by your server and not be available/visible in the source code (unless I missed a super cool new feature) of your page

Comment: You're absolutely right, what I meant was the php in my views. My background is with Vue.js and Angular, I tend to think of that as the php in my between my html as "in-line" and the "front-end".